# bash: "which adb" returns nothing, but "command -v adb" returns what i'd expect

Tags: bash, macos, path, command

This is a bash weirdness that's been bugging me.

I'm on OSX.

I've installed the android SDK, and as a result the `adb` tool is located in a folder in my home directory. That folder appears in my path as reported by `env` as `~/Development/android_sdk_latest/platform-tools`.

`adb` itself runs just fine, but when I do `which adb` the result is empty. If I do `command -v adb`, the result is the full path, as expected: `/Users/me/Development/android_sdk_latest/platform-tools/adb`

`adb` does not appear in my aliases.

What subtlety of bash paths or `which` am I in the dark on?

Comment: What does `type adb` give you? And do you have a literal `~` character in your `$PATH`?

Comment: @KeithThompson - `adb is hashed (/Users/me/Development/android_sdk_latest/platform-tools/adb)`,
and i think, yes, i do. I set the path up by `source`ing a script with this line: `export PATH="$PATH:~/Development/android_sdk_latest/platform-tools"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've run into a subtle incompatibility between `/bin/bash` and the `which` command.

On my system (Linux Mint), the `which` command is actually a shell script, not a built-in command, and its first line is `#! /bin/sh`. That means that it uses `/bin/sh`'s handling of the `$PATH` variable.

This can vary depending on how `/bin/sh` is set up (it's sometimes a symlink to `/bin/bash`), but a little experimentation shows that `bash` handles a literal `~` character in `$PATH` as if it were the full path to your home directory, but `/bin/sh` does not. Since you have

```
~/Development/android_sdk_latest/platform-tools
```

as one of the elements of your `$PATH`, `bash` (your interactive shell) can find the `adb` command, but `sh` (the shell used by `which`) cannot.

On some systems, apparently including your OSX system, `which` is a binary executable. Again, since it's not a bash script, it's not going to match bash's treatment of `$PATH`.

I recommend making two changes.

First, don't put a literal `~` in your `$PATH`. For example, to append the `platform-tools` directory to your `$PATH`, rather than this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/Development/android_sdk_latest/platform-tools" # BAD!
```

do this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Development/android_sdk_latest/platform-tools"
```

The `$HOME` will expand to the path to your home directory (when you run the `export` command, not when you use `$PATH` later). `~` is not expanded within double-quoted strings.

Second, rather than using the `which` command, use the `type` command that's built into `bash`. `type` will follow the rules of your current shell rather than those of `/bin/sh`, and it will be able to report shell functions and aliases that `which` is unable to see. It has several useful command-line options; type `help type` at a bash prompt for details.

The bash shell's treatement of `~` characters in `$PATH` is documented in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/)'s section on [Tilde Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html).

Comment: dead-on!
with the exception that my `which` (/usr/bin/which) seems to be a binary rather than a script.

thanks for the tip about $HOME. i made that change and `which` now agrees with `command`.

i did not know about `type`.  that's a great tool!

Comment: @orionelenzil: Interesting. I suppose I shouldn't be surprised that it's different on OSX. But I'm not at all surprised that a (probably C) implementation of `which` also wouldn't handle `~` in `$PATH`.