# Haskell stack won't upgrade

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to upgrade my copy of Haskell's stack, as shown below:

```
mac:~ me$ stack --version
Version 1.4.0, Git revision e714f1dd3fade19496d91bd6a017e435a96a6bcd (4640 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.17.0
mac:~ me$ stack upgrade
Current Stack version: 1.4.0, available download version: 1.7.1
Newer version detected, downloading
Querying for archive location for platform: osx-x86_64-static
Querying for archive location for platform: osx-x86_64
Downloading from: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/releases/download/v1.7.1/stack-1.7.1-osx-x86_64.tar.gz
Download complete, testing executable
Version 1.7.1, Git revision 681c800873816c022739ca7ed14755e85a579565 (5807 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.28.2
New stack executable available at /Users/me/.local/bin/stack
mac:~ me$ stack --version
Version 1.4.0, Git revision e714f1dd3fade19496d91bd6a017e435a96a6bcd (4640 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.17.0
mac:~ me$ which stack
/Users/me/.local/bin/stack
```

Why does `stack upgrade` seem to correctly upgrade stack, claiming to install a new version, and then even say `New stack executable available at /Users/me/.local/bin/stack`, but not actually upgrade the stack version when tested, the `which` command confirming that it is indeed the location of the new stack executable that is run?

#### Update:

Thanks to a suggestion from Probie, I checked whether `/Users/me/.local/bin/stack --version` reports the updated version, and **it does**:

```
mac:~ me$ /Users/me/.local/bin/stack --version
Version 1.7.1, Git revision 681c800873816c022739ca7ed14755e85a579565 (5807 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.28.2
```

This has me thoroughly confused, for this reason:

```
mac:~ me$ /Users/me/.local/bin/stack --version
Version 1.7.1, Git revision 681c800873816c022739ca7ed14755e85a579565 (5807 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.28.2
mac:~ me$ which stack
/Users/me/.local/bin/stack
mac:~ me$ stack --version
Version 1.4.0, Git revision e714f1dd3fade19496d91bd6a017e435a96a6bcd (4640 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.17.0
```

Why does the version of stack run with the `stack` command show a different version from the one at the location shown by the `which stack` command?

Comment: Can you confirm that `/Users/me/.local/bin/stack --version` gives the incorrect version?

Comment: @Probie Updated above, which is even more confusing

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

It turns out it's just that `which` isn't returning the correct result as far as bash is concerned. [It might be related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579921/bash-which-adb-returns-nothing-but-command-v-adb-returns-what-id-expect)

---

In all likelihood it's just that bash has cached the location of stack, and isn't using the new one.

Try running `hash stack` and then trying it again. (Or if that fails `hash -r` to empty the cache)

Comment: No dice, neither `hash stack` nor `hash -r` nor `hash -r stack` changed the output of `stack --version`

Comment: Also worth nothing that I've closed and reopened bash any number of times since I first tried this upgrade, and it had been quite a while since I first encountered this issue that I decided to post about it here

Comment: What does `type stack` give you?

Comment: Now we're onto something. `stack is hashed (/Users/me/<path-that-isn't-in-.local>/stack)`

Comment: `which` ignores the shell's hash table. Are you running some sort of strange shell, or just bash?

Comment: I'm running iTerm 2

Comment: What does `echo $0` say?

Comment: It says `-bash`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176004/discussion-between-probie-and-theenvironmentalist).